# Serverless authorizer as AWS user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless

I'm trying to limit access on a service endpoints to a specific user pool (ie admin).

From my understanding of the documentation (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/) this should be possible by setting

```
get:
  handler: functions/get.main
  events:
    - http:
        path: /
        method: get
        cors: true
        authorizer: "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-2:####:userpool/eu-west-2_xET8A8Kui"
```

Deploys fine and appears correctly in the API gateway for this endpoint

[image: screen shot of API gateway]

Problem is any calls via AWS Amplify (React integration) to the API result in a 401 error! If I put the authorizer back to `aws_iam` it works fine.

Where can I even begin to debug this? I can't find any specific logs or reason why this is failing.

Answer (score 1):

How you have things setup should work (I have that working - just a User Pool).

You will need to pass the `idToken` you received from your Amplify auth call in the `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiJ4T2NLWG5GakljWE...
```

Make sure to use the idToken, not the accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked amplify only supported IAM Auth not user pool auth. You can use an identity pool with your user pool and still use IAM via your user pool.